# How to select meshes with transparent materials applied to them only?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, objects

I want to select all meshes which a transparent material (e.g. glass) has been applied, when using Cycles (if it matters at all)? I just know how to select meshes with any kind of material applied to them as follow:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                obj.select = True
```

How can I instead only select meshes with transparent materials? You can also work with nodes. In that case, you may want to download [this](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/vDrn38sqGffvcWwDpIJTbuvUyNPYoyR57uDYmTkKfCE) object that I'm currently using and need to select its transparent meshes. If you want to use the mesh I am providing, select Cycles renderer first and then load the mesh you will get something like this in the node editor:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally determining if a given node setup is transparent is rather tricky; for instance, a material may be transparent only in some areas (textured transparency) and other such complications. However, *in your case*, it seems that checking if the value of the "Mix Color/Alpha" node is < 1 should be sufficient.

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                mat = slot.material
                for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.label == "Mix Color/Alpha":
                        if node.inputs[1].default_value[0] < 1:
                            print("Material '%s' on object '%s' seems transparent" % (mat.name, obj.name))
```

The importer seems to create both cycles and BI materials, so you could also check the BI material property (even while cycles is active):

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                mat = slot.material
                if mat.use_transparency:
                    print("Material '%s' on object '%s' seems transparent" % (mat.name, obj.name))
```

Comment: Could be more efficient to go the other way, ie make a set of material names  that may be transparent (`for mat in bpy.data.materials:`) and then check on a per `o in scene.objects` basis if the set made from `o.material_slots.keys()` intersects your transparent materials set.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to add relevant nodes like what you suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101589/how-to-render-depth-or-surface-normal-maps-that-properly-reflect-details-of-3d-s/101765#101765) to these transparent materials through Python? If so, would it be possible for you to update your code in my new question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101820/how-to-add-shader-nodes-and-corresponding-links-to-meshes-with-transparent-mater) so that I can add the shader nodes and their corresponding links easily?