# How to render world-space surface Normal maps using Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

This is a similar question to what I had asked before. But this time I want to render camera view-invariant (world-space) surface Normal maps using Blender Internal renderer. How can I do that?

In Cycles, I can get something like the followings which are consistent no matter what the camera angle is:

[image]

[image]

But using Blender Internal, I get something like this which changes as the camera angle changes:

[image]

[image]

You can download the *.blend* file with the object and cameras from here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a "Normals" material using nodes:

   [image]
2. Apply it to all objects. The *Material Override* option in *Properties > Render Layers* may be useful for this, but if you want to preserve transparency of existing materials you may have to tweak every material individually, ideally with python scripting:

   I'd suggest [making a node group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5387/599) containing the geometry node (so future tweaking is easier), connecting that group's output to the *Color* input of every material's output node, and setting the *Alpha* according to [however you decide a material is transparent or not](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/101766/599).  Here is [an example of some node scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5336/599), hopefully that helps.
3. Enable *World Space Shading* in *Properties > Shading*:

   [image]

Render:

[image]